# Am I using flex correctly in this situation?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

Say I want to a container of courses that would look something like this

[image]

Is this bad making essentially each part of the "course" it's own flexbox?

```css
.course-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.course-options {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.course-title {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.course-grade {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="course-container">
  <div class="course">
    <div class="course-options">
      <i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg' aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class='fa fa-trash-o fa-lg' aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="course-title">
      <a href="">Course 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="course-grade">
      <a href="">Grade: 0.00%</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="course">
    <div class="course-options">
      <i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg' aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class='fa fa-trash-o fa-lg' aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="course-title">
      <a href="">Course 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="course-grade">
      <a href="">Grade: 0.00%</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks goot to me. As long it suits your needs - there in no right or wrong I would say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with how you set it up, and whether it is the best is very much dependent on how a `course` box should behave.

With what I know now, you could optimize that code, which I would, and achieve the same result.

Here I removed all inner wrappers and used [auto margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins), which got an upgrade with Flexbox, that make it easy to align items within its parent.

The benefit with a structure like this, besides being having a lot less markup, you have endless ways to reorder the items based on content or screen sizes.

Stack snippet

```css
.course-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.course {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;   /*  align to top, and prevent from stretch  */
  width: 250px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
.course .fa-trash-o,
.course .grade {
  margin-left: auto;         /*  push trash and grade to the right  */
}
.course .grade {
  margin-top: auto;          /*  push to bottom  */
}
.course .title {
  flex-basis: 100%;          /*  take full width, make it wrap on a row of its own  */
  margin: auto 0;            /*  center vertically  */
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="course-container">
  <div class="course">
      <i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg' aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class='fa fa-trash-o fa-lg' aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <a class='title' href="">Course 1</a>
      <a class='grade' href="">Grade: 0.00%</a>
  </div>
  <div class="course">
      <i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg' aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class='fa fa-trash-o fa-lg' aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <a class='title' href="">Course 2</a>
      <a class='grade' href="">Grade: 0.00%</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define `display: flex` on each inner element, you can use `align-self` instead.

```css
.course-container,
.course {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.course {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.course-options {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.course-title {
  align-self: center;
}

.course-grade {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="course-container">
  <div class="course">
    <div class="course-options">
      <i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg' aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class='fa fa-trash-o fa-lg' aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="course-title">
      <a href="">Course 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="course-grade">
      <a href="">Grade: 0.00%</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="course">
    <div class="course-options">
      <i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg' aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class='fa fa-trash-o fa-lg' aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="course-title">
      <a href="">Course 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="course-grade">
      <a href="">Grade: 0.00%</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This situation does NOT require flexbox. Flexbox still has [less than 90% browser support worldwide](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex) (unprefixed), so I would not use it yet, unless you have absolutely no alternative.

This is a proper solution that works in all browsers:

```css
.card {
  text-align: center; 
  position: relative; 
  width: 100%; 
  max-width: 300px; 
  height: 100px; 
  line-height: 100px; 
  border: 1px solid black; 
  margin: 5px;
}
.card > * {line-height: 1.4em; position: absolute;}
.card > .edit {left: 0; top: 0;}
.card > .delete {right: 0; top: 0;}
.card > .grade {right: 0; bottom: 0;}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <a href="#" class="edit">edit</a>
  <a href="#" class="delete">delete</a>
  <span class="grade">grade</span>
  course 1
</div>
<div class="card">
  <a href="#" class="edit">edit</a>
  <a href="#" class="delete">delete</a>
  <span class="grade">grade</span>
  course 2
</div>
```